# How to change section number to relabel theorems(newtcbtheorem 3.1 to 1.1) while preserving sections in progress bar in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, numbering, bar

Here is my MWE: I have a two sections(Review and Summary) before my First section (section 3) and Second sections (section 4). So Theorems in my First/Second sections get numbered Theorem 3.1 and Theorem 4.1 because they are really in the third/fourth sections. I would like to relabel sections so the First section is labelled section 1, the Second section is labelled section 2 and so forth so that theorems get labelled Theorem 1.1 instead of Theorem 3.1 in my First section and so forth, but **without affecting the progress bar** so that in the progress bar it is still shows that it is moving in the third/fourth sections when in these corresponding renumbered sections:i.e.
section 3 -> First section -> renumbered section 1 but moving in section 3 of progress bar
section 4 -> Second section -> renumbered section 2 but moving in section 4 of progress bar
I tried \setcounter{section}{0}\renewcommand{\thesection} before the Summary section an it did not work.

### MWE output

Review
Summary
First section
Theorem **3.1**

Second Section
Theorem **4.1**

Progress bar shows moving in Review, Summary then First then Second section (which is the third and fourth section); good

### Wanted

Review
Summary
First section
Theorem **1.1**

Second section
Theorem **2.1**

Progress bar should be moving the same way as in MWE from Review to Summary to First and Second sections   even after having renumbered the sections 3 and 4 (First and Second section) sections 1 and 2 to get proper theorem numbering

```
\documentclass[slidetop, 11pt, leqno, french, english]{beamer}  
\begin{filecontents}{Mybib.bib}
@article{au20,
     Author = {Author1},
     Journal = {journal},
     Pages = {56-80},
     Title = {Title},
     Volume = {2},
     Year = {2020}}
@article{au19,
     Author = {Author2},
     Journal = {journal},
     Pages = {20-40},
     Title = {Title},
     Volume = {10},
     Year = {2019}}
@article{au86,
     Author = {Author3},
     Journal = {journal},
     Pages = {23-56},
     Title = {Title},
     Volume = {15},
     Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcites{ra}{Review}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{arydshln}  

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\setcounter{section}{0}\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{lem}{Lemma}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{thm}{Theorem}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{cor}{Corollary}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\definecolor{bluegreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.57,0.5}
\usecolortheme[named=bluegreen]{structure}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliographystylera{apalike}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[Author]{Author}

\def\vs{\vspace*{0.3cm}}

\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Review}
\bibliographyra{Mybib}
\vs
Some review material in order:\\
\vs
Some topics first: \citera{au19} \\
Some more topics second: \citera{au20} 
\end{frame}

\section{Summary}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}{}{}
an important result
\end{thm}
Proof: uses the \nameref{th:stat} in \ref{th:stat}
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}{}{}
An even more important result.
\end{thm}
Proof: Also uses \nameref{th:stat} in \ref{th:stat} and \nameref{th:stat2} in \ref{th:stat2} and \cite{au86}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
\bibliography{Mybib}
\end{frame}

\appendix
\section{Appendix A}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}{Stat lemma}{stat}
Statement of the lemma here
\end{thm}
\end{frame}
\section{Appendix B}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}{Another Stat lemma}{stat2}
Statement of the lemma here
\end{thm}
\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer. Any further help would be appreciated.
After looking into the tcolorbox manual I figured I could create a new section counter which I called newsect and use it instead of section in the theorem command

```
\newcounter{newsect}[enumi]
\AtAppendix{\setcounter{newsect}{0}\renewcommand{\thenewsect}{\Alph{section}}} % needed for appendix  
% with another command before the appendix see full code  
\newtcbtheorem[number within=newsect]{lem}{Lemma}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=newsect]{thm}{Theorem}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=newsect]{cor}{Corollary}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
```

and then set the counter newsect before each section
the tcolorbox manual says: p.113

/tcb/new/number within=〈counter〉(no default, initially unset)
**The automatic counter is set to zero, if〈counter〉is increased.** Additionally, during output,the value of〈counter〉is prepended to the value of the automatic counter.To prepend the automatic counter with the chapter number and to reset it with every new chapter, use:number within=chapter

so I thought when my counter newsect is incremented by a manual increment before a section, that the automatic numbering would get reset, i.e. the number in number within=newsect would reset, it appears not to...I figure it has to do with the fact that my newsect counter is really not like a \section or \chapter so I must be missing a lot of coding to get it to work like that.

So I managed to get the numbering of the sections renumbered **while preserving the corresponding progress in the sections in the progress bar** since it is only in the theorem/lemma/corollary defs it does not affect the progress bar sections, so that works well, but now my counter number does not get reset.

### MWE gives

Review
Summary
First section
Theorem 1.1

Theorem 1.2

Second Section
Theorem 2.**3**

Theorem 2.**4**

Appendix A

Theorem A.**5**

Appendix B

Theorem B.**6**

while preserving the progress bar sections

### Wanted

Review
Summary
First section
Theorem 1.1

Theorem 1.2

Second Section
Theorem 2.**1**

Theorem 2.**2**

Appendix A

Theorem A.**1**

Appendix B

Theorem B.**1**

while preserving the progress bar sections

I tried a suggestion I read on a post on how to manipulate number counters in tcolorbox and tcbtheorem command but I could not get it to work, specifically in the call to the theorem add a code= command as in:

```
\begin{thm}[code={\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{1}}]{}{} % 
An even more important result.
\end{thm}
```

I would need to know how to reset the number in number within=newsect when the counter newsect gets increased manually or otherwise to make the reseting of number work, that is while using a new counter in the within= part!

Here is the full code of the new MWE

```
\documentclass[slidetop, 11pt, leqno, french, english]{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{Mybib.bib}
@article{au20,
     Author = {Author1},
     Journal = {journal},
     Pages = {56-80},
     Title = {Title},
     Volume = {2},
     Year = {2020}}
@article{au19,
     Author = {Author2},
     Journal = {journal},
     Pages = {20-40},
     Title = {Title},
     Volume = {10},
     Year = {2019}}
@article{au86,
     Author = {Author3},
     Journal = {journal},
     Pages = {23-56},
     Title = {Title},
     Volume = {15},
     Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcites{ra}{Review}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{apptools}
%\AtAppendix{\setcounter{section}{0}\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{newsect}[enumi]
\AtAppendix{\setcounter{newsect}{0}\renewcommand{\thenewsect}{\Alph{section}}}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=newsect]{lem}{Lemma}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=newsect]{thm}{Theorem}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=newsect]{cor}{Corollary}%
{colback=white,colframe=bluegreen,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\definecolor{bluegreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.57,0.5}
\usecolortheme[named=bluegreen]{structure}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliographystylera{apalike}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[Author]{Author}

\def\vs{\vspace*{0.3cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliographyra{Mybib}
\vs
Some review material in order:\\
\vs
Some topics first: \citera{au19} \\
Some more topics second: \citera{au20} 
\end{frame}

\section{Summary}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setcounter{newsect}{1}
\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}{}{}
an important result
\end{thm}
Proof: uses the \nameref{th:stat} in \ref{th:stat}
\begin{thm}{}{}
a second important result
\end{thm}
Proof: uses the \nameref{th:stat} in \ref{th:stat}
\end{frame}

% \setcounter{newsect}{2} does not work either
\addtocounter{newsect}{1}
\section{Second section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}[code={\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{10}}]{}{} % from a suggestion this might work but it does not
An even more important result.
\end{thm}
Proof: Also uses \nameref{th:stat} in \ref{th:stat} and \nameref{th:stat2} in \ref{th:stat2} and \cite{au86}
\begin{thm}{}{}
A second even more important result.
\end{thm}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
\bibliography{Mybib}
\end{frame}

\AtAppendix{\setcounter{section}{0}\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}}
\appendix
\section{Appendix A}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}{Stat lemma}{stat}
Statement of the lemma here
\end{thm}
\end{frame}
\section{Appendix B}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}{Another Stat lemma}{stat2}
Statement of the lemma here
\end{thm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```